# xQuery 1.0, element counting

Tags: count, xquery, sections

I have a problem with writting a XQuery. I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
  <title>Data</title>
  <author>Serge Abiteboul</author>
  <author>Peter Buneman</author>
  <author>Dan Suciu</author>
  <section id="intro" difficulty="easy" >
    <title>Chapter1</title>
    <p>Text ... </p>
    <section>
      <title>SubChapter1</title>
      <p>Text ... </p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <title>SubChapter2</title>
      <p>Text ... </p>
      <figure height="400" width="400">
        <title>Figure1</title>
        <image source="csarch.gif"/>
      </figure>
      <p>Text ... </p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section id="syntax" difficulty="medium" >
    <title>Chapter2</title>
    <p>Text ... </p>
    <figure height="200" width="500">
      <title>Figure2</title>
      <image source="graphs.gif"/>
    </figure>
    <p>Text ... </p>
    <section>
      <title>SubChapter3</title>
      <p>Text ... </p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <title>SubChapter6</title>
      <p>Text ... </p>
      <figure height="250" width="400">
        <title>Figure3</title>
        <image source="relations.gif"/>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section>
      <title>SubChapter5</title>
      <p>Text ... </p>
    </section>       
  </section>
</book>
```

I have to write a Xquery that will count every SubChapter in a Chapter, and every figure in each. I got to this point so far:

```
    for $x in doc("file.xml")/book
    return ((<main>{data($x/title)}</main>),
(<mChapter nrSubChapter="{count($x/section/title)}" nrFigure="{count($x/section/section/figure)}">{***data($x/section/title)***}</mChapter>),
    (<mChapter nrSubChapter="{count($x/section/title}" nrFigures="{count($x//figure)}">{***data($x/section/title)***}</mChapter>))
```

Also I don't know how to put the title of the chapter on the places marked with ***.

Comment: And where are you stuck? Any error message, is the output not as you expect? Please read [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Especially of importance is your current output (or any error messages you receive), and the expected output (matching the example input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things I don't understand in your sample query.  First of all, `for $x in doc(...)/*` will not loop over several nodes, as there is one root element in an XML document (it's a lie, but let's pretend there is no exception, for simplicity).

Your usage of parenthesis makes the query quite hard to read also.  Why not using a more natural XML structure for the output?

What you want to do is to retrive something from the whole book (the title), then loop over sections, then *for each of them*, loop over its own (sub-)sections.

```
let $book := doc('file.xml')/book
return
   <result>
      <main>{ xs:string($book/title) }</main>
      {
         for $section in $book/section
         return
            <chapter nrSubChapter="{ count($section/section) }"
                     nrFigure="{ count($section/figure) }">
               <title>{ xs:string($section/title) }</title>
               {
                  for $sub in $section/section
                  return
                     <section nrFigure="{ count($sub/figure) }">
                        <title>{ xs:string($sub/title) }</title>
                     </section>
               }
            </chapter>
      }
   </result>
```

If you can have several levels of sections, you will have to use recursion.

Also, as Jens said, you have not told us the exact output format you want, so I just give you an idea how to solve this, you'll have to adapt it to your precise requirements.

PS: Note I did NOT test the code.

Comment: A wasn't getting any error. I just got stuck with my code because I did not know how to count every section and every figure. You showed me how to do that and now I am able to write my xquery without a problem. I'm sorry for not defining the output but the output was irrelevant. Anyway. THANK YOU. You were really really really helpful.